# How to apply (make real) a curve generated by modifier in Graph Editor?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I need to apply (or make real) modifier used on IPO curve for next adjustment.

In my case I have curve with three keyframes plus Modifier (type Cycles) that repeats eight times this step. 
I have many similar animated objects with modifier. And I need to edit each curve individually later (after applying modifier).

Does exist function in blender that make this modifier real?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 7):

Select object, hit <kbd>SPACE BAR</kbd>, write **Bake Action** and Enter.
In pop-up properties window you can keep default setup for this purpose.
Confirm, that's it.

[image]

Comment: This only works if you're on a SRT curve. Not on shape animated curves.

Answer (score 5):

IPO is the old call for the current Graph Editor. I suppose you are using Blender 2.6x:

When in Graph Editor, go to the editor menu **Key** > **Bake Curve** (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), to bake/apply the modified result and overwrite the existing curve. However, The modifiers are still there unless you manually remove them.

**CAUTION:** you CANNOT re-edit that curve anymore after that. So, make sure that's what you can really afford.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't write it clearly. I edited my question a bit - because that's what I need - edit curve after modifier is applied. I can't believe there is not an option for that. I don't want to mess this topic, but for does it good for baked curve that can't be edited? Thank you for help.

Comment: Should I change title to something relevant. So others can find it easier? Like "How to apply (make real) curve generated by modifier in Graph Editor?"

Comment: Perhaps. Another idea: try **Bake Action** (you can find it in Spacebar list), then simplify the result curve, which may work in some cases. I don't think there currently is any straight operator for you other than that.

Comment: Btw, there is an addon called **Simplify Curves** that is much useful in this case, and very easy to use.

Comment: **OK, thank you for your help.** Bake action is quite good tip :) Simplify Curve - I know it, one of my favorite :) But in this case I need precise position and when I simplify curve to a level of control points that I need for edit, I loose precise position. Shame, my "Q" seems to me as simple function for blender :(